# Do Kerbal Contracts recur?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In Kerbal Space Program 0.24 the new contract system has been introduced.

Do contracts recur, that is, if I do a mission once, will it come up again?

I don't want to be repetitive doing the same missions over and over again. If they do come up more than once, is there a way to get out of doing them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first contracts you get from the record-keeping society as well as the "explore [Planet/Moon]" contracts are not repeatable, but all other contracts are randomly-generated. Those contract types which don't have very specific requirements feel kind of repetitive. Especially the "retrieve science from Kerbin orbit" contract seems to repeat indefinitely - only the name of the client seems to change.

But you do not have to accept any contracts you don't like. You can decline any unaccepted contract <strike>without a penalty</strike>, although there is a small prestige penalty for this since version 1.1. Most contracts will then get immediately replaced with a similar one. When you ignore new contracts, they will expire after a few days and also get replaced, in that case without a prestige penalty.

Comment: Parts testing contracts seem to repeat fairly regularly with variation - for example, completing the parachute contract under certain height/speed conditions repeated again and again with differences in height and speed.

Comment: @HorusKol There is only a limited number of functional parts, so the amount of part tests which can be randomly generated is equally limited. However, the different speed and height parameters still make these tests quite interesting, especially when you try to complete multiple ones in one launch.